# Make Kotlin models Serializable using swagger codegen

Tags: kotlin, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate my API logic using swagger codegen. However, I need to implement java.io.Serializable for the generated models.
I tried to add the following:

```
"serializeModel": true
```

to the config.json file, which didn't do anything.
My generated models come out like this:

```
package dms.models


/**
 * 
 * @param id 
 * @param name 
 */
data class GetCompanyResponse (

    val id: kotlin.Int? = null,
    val name: kotlin.String? = null
) {
}
```

But I need them to be like this:

```
package dms.models

import java.io.Serializable


/**
 * 
 * @param id 
 * @param name 
 */
data class GetCompanyResponse (

    val id: kotlin.Int? = null,
    val name: kotlin.String? = null
): Serializable {
}
```

My config.json looks like this:

```
{
  "modelPackage": "dms.models",
  "apiPackage": "dms.api",
  "serializableModel": true
}
```

And the script I call to generate looks like this:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i $SWAGGER_URL -l $CLIENT -o $OUT_DIR -D modelDocs=$MODEL_DOCS -D apiTests=$API_TESTS -D apiDocs=$API_DOCS --config config.json
```

Does anyone know what I need to change in order for this to work?
I am using swagger codegen v3.0.25

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any updates?

Comment: @AlexandraFilyakova I did not find a simple fix, but I'm glad I took the solution I am using now. What I did was create a business layer between my app and the swagger models, where the API-calls are made and where the Swagger models are rebuilt into my own models (which are Serializable). This way I can also implement vars instead of vals, so I am able to mutate my data later on in my application. If you need a simple example just ask ;)